# Sumar y restar en una tabla SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta para poder obtener el balance total, es decir, sumar todas las celdas donde el campo `operation` es `IN` para luego restar a este valor, todas las celdas donde el valor del campo `operation` es `OUT`.

La consulta para sumar y restar la tenga hecha. Lo que no se es si puedo realizar todo en una misma consulta ya que lo quiero usar en una pagina web con una consulta sql utilizando `php`.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as income FROM tabla1 WHERE operation="IN";
SELECT SUM(amount) as expense FROM tabla1 WHERE operation="OUT";
```

Se me ocurre crear un campo pero no se si se actualiza automáticamente o hay que ejecutar la consulta cada vez.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede hacer como indicas con un campo EN OTRA TABLA que se actualice con un trigger cada vez que se inserte un registro en tabla1 pero no es muy recomendable tener un campo en una base de datos que puede calcularse a partir de otros campos ya almacenados.

Puedes obtener los parciales y el total en una sola consulta.

```
SELECT CTE.INCOME, CTE.OUTCOME, (CTE.INCOME - CTE.OUTCOME) AS TOTAL 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION='IN' THEN COALESCE(AMOUNT,0) ELSE 0 END) AS INCOME,
           SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION='OUT' THEN COALESCE(AMOUNT,0) ELSE 0 END) AS OUTCOME
    FROM TABLA1
) CTE;
```

He usado la operación COALESCE porque no sé si permites NULL en ese campo. Si no hay ningún registro cuya operación sea IN, obtendremos un 0 como INCOME. Y lo mismo para la operación OUT y el OUTCOME.

Empleando los siguientes datos de prueba

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA1 (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  OPERATION varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  AMOUNT int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO TABLA1(ID, OPERATION, AMOUNT) VALUE (1,'IN',100);
INSERT INTO TABLA1(ID, OPERATION, AMOUNT) VALUE (2,'IN',200);
INSERT INTO TABLA1(ID, OPERATION, AMOUNT) VALUE (3,'IN',NULL);
INSERT INTO TABLA1(ID, OPERATION, AMOUNT) VALUE (4,'OUT',50);
INSERT INTO TABLA1(ID, OPERATION, AMOUNT) VALUE (5,'OUT',25);
```

Obtendriamos el siguiente resultado

```
INCOME  OUTCOME TOTAL
300     75      225
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Desconocía la operación COALESCE pero me ha servido para lo que buscaba.

Comment: @winset De nada. Esa operación es para tratar los valores nulos, puedes omitirla si ya has establecido esa restricción para el campo al crear la tabla. Quizás es más relevante el CASE WHEN y usar una subconsulta para poder llevar a cabo la resta de los totales.